# Specify NSPrincipalClass in Xcode 13 for a library project

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode13

I need to specify an NSPrincipalClass. This used to be done using an Info.plist but when creating a Library in Xcode 13 an Info.plist is no longer created. Can an NSPrincipalClass be specified in the Package.swift manifest instead? I have not found any documentation that explains how to do this in Xcode 13 created projects.

Comment: What do you need `NSPrincipalClass` for? Why is it important for your library?

Comment: For testing purposes only. Registering an XCTestObserver as described in the overview section here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestobservationcenter

Comment: OK, so your goal is to be able to register `XCTestObserver`'s in a unit test target for a library? Regardless if it's done via `NSPrincipalClass` or not?

Comment: That is the primary goal yes, it wouldn't necessarily have to be done via NSPrincipalClass, but it did raise the question as how to start up code is now supposed to be handled in Xcode13 created projects.

Comment: This has little to do with Xcode, static libraries never had an `Info.plist`.